# How to stop python Apscheduler on some condition

Tags: python, apscheduler

Actually am learning python APScheduler in this am trying one example

```
d={'a':{'status':'n'},'b':{'status':'n'},'c':{'status':'y'}}
```

The scheduler what i added is like below

```
for k,v in d.items():
if d[k]['status']=='n':
    sched.add_interval_job(f,minutes=1)
    d[k]['status']='y'
```

But this **scheduler starts** every **1 minute** and call function **f**,how to **stop scheduler calling this function, f** if their are **no entries in dict with status 'n'** and how to **continue this scheduler calling** if their are entries with **status 'n' in dict d.**

Answer (score 1):

You can unschedule jobs using `sched.unschedule_job(job_function.job)` as per [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/intervalschedule.html).